# Parallelized `Find` loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

There are several packages in R to simplify running code in parallel, like `foreach` and `future`. Most of these have constructs which are like `lapply` or a for loop: they carry on until all the tasks have finished.

Is there a simple parallel version of `Find`? That is, I would like to run several tasks in parallel. I don't need all of them to finish, I just need to get the first one that finishes (maybe with a particular result). After that the other tasks can be killed, or left to finish on their own.

Conceptual code:

```
hunt_needle <- function (x, y) x %in% (y-1000):y

x <- sample.int(1000000, 1) 

result <- parallel_find(seq(1000, 1000000, 1000), hunt_needle)
# should return the first value for which hunt_needle is true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared memory so that processes can communicate with one another.
For that, you can use package **bigstatsr** (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Choose a block size and do:

```
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
library(bigstatsr)

# Data example
cond <- logical(1e6)
cond[sample(length(cond), size = 1)] <- TRUE

ind.block <- bigstatsr:::CutBySize(length(cond), block.size = 1000)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(nb_cores())
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

# This value (in an on-disk matrix) is shared by processes
found_it <- FBM(1, 1, type = "integer", init = 0L)

library(foreach)
res <- foreach(ic = sample(rows_along(ind.block)), .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  if (found_it[1]) return(NULL)
  ind <- bigstatsr:::seq2(ind.block[ic, ])
  find <- which(cond[ind])
  if (length(find)) {
    found_it[1] <- 1L
    return(ind[find[1]])
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

# Verification
all.equal(res, which(cond))
```

Basically, when a solution is found, you don't need to do some computations anymore, and others know it because you put a `1` in `found_it` which is shared between all processes.

As your question is not reproducible and I don't understand everything you need, you may have to adapt this solution a little bit.

Comment: Nice but a bit hackish. There's nothing off the shelf?

Comment: Let me expand on "a bit hackish"... the processes use shared memory, but why shouldn't the parent process just realise when it gets a result and kill the remaining children? This seems more elegant.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that surely with MPI, but it's harder to use and to install. I use shared memory to reimplement things like message passing, barriers, etc.

Comment: That indeed looks interesting. Thank you.